# How can I trim a string if input is Ramesh-123-india ...my desire output should be only "india""

Tags: javascript, string, trim

In material table one of the column has to be trim ..for example input is ramesh-123-india ,the output should be come as only "india"....how to do this

Comment: Does every work from that column have suffix india ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking into the `split()`.
[JavaScript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

You can pass in a string pattern that it searches for to split it up.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can make use of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) here

```js
const str = "ramesh-123-india";
const result = str.split("-")[2];

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also use regex  `/\w+$/` here as:

[image]

```js
const str = "ramesh-123-india";
const result = str.match(/\w+$/)[0];

console.log(result);
```